# Database doesn't update when I edit texboxes in Tkinter. Error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I can't update the values of two textboxes. My goal is to change the value of the textboxes and click the Update_Value button to update the database.

I get this error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

What do I want to achieve? In the textbox `x` the value `50` is displayed. In the textbox `y` the value `60` is displayed. For example, i would like to modify the textbox `x` and replace `50` with `55`, then i click on the button. So I would like the value `50`, having `id = 1`, to be replaced with `55` in the database. The same thing with the textobox `y` which corresponds to `id = 2`

```
x = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
x.place(x=420, y=30)

y = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
y.place(x=420, y=55)

def Update_Value():
    new_connection = sqlite3.connect('...')
    connect = new_connection.cursor()

    connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori=?", (x.get(), y.get(),))

button1 = Button(root, text="Update Value", command= Update_Value)
button1.place(x=0, y=0)
```

The simple database is:

```
CREATE TABLE "Valori_Textbox" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "valori"    INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

INSERT INTO Valori_Textbox
  (`valori``)
VALUES
  ('50'),
  ('60');
```

Comment: your query makes no sense you have one placeholder but three values. also your update will update all rows. Maybe you need to rethink your approch

Comment: @nbk I know there's a problem. That's why I asked the question, otherwise I wouldn't have asked anything. Can you help me please?

Comment: Well, what are you expecting here?  Your database has two rows, each of which has one value and an id that you don't know.  What to expect to do with your two values, x and y?  Show us a sample.  What would the database look like after your change?

Comment: @Tim Roberts In the textbox x the value 50 is displayed. In the textbox x the value 60 is displayed. For example, I would like to modify the textbox x and replace 50 with 55, then I click on the button. So I would like the value 50, having id = 1, to be replaced with 55 in the database. The same thing with the textobox y which corresponds to id = 2

Comment: as i said i don't understand what you try to do  basically it mu s moll like https://dbfiddle.uk/BOADYgRi  so you need for every id you own update.

Comment: @nbk Yes, I was looking for this. Thank you. A curiosity please. You said that my query doesn't make sense and that I need to rethink my approach. So I ask you: is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an answer for your question you can add in two ways

Update seperately based on id

```
# Update the row with id=1
connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori=? WHERE id=1", (x.get(),))

# Update the row with id=2
connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori=? WHERE id=2", (y.get(),))
```

or Update them in a single line

```
connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN ? WHEN 2 THEN ? END", (x.get(), y.get()))
```

either these two will update the values of the two rows accordingly

To give you full script try below - Hope this helps

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def Update_Value():
    new_connection = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')  # Replace with your database file
    connect = new_connection.cursor()

    connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN ? WHEN 2 THEN ? END", (x.get(), y.get()))

    new_connection.commit()  # Commit the changes to the database
    new_connection.close()   # Close the database connection

root = tk.Tk()

x = ttk.Entry(root, width=7)
x.place(x=420, y=30)

y = ttk.Entry(root, width=7)
y.place(x=420, y=55)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Update Value", command=Update_Value)
button1.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It updates both rows in your database in a single go based on the contents of your two input boxes that corresponds to the ID in the database.

**Pythonic ways to update if the ID's value keeps on increasing like 1,2,3...**

```
values_to_update = [x.get(), y.get(), z.get()]  # Add more values if needed

for i, value in enumerate(values_to_update, start=1):
    connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori = ? WHERE id = ?", (value, i))
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Thank you. A curiosity please. Another very kind user like you, in a comment, told me that my query doesn't make sense and that I need to rethink my approach. So I ask you: is there a better approach?

Comment: `connect.execute("UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET valori=?", (x.get(), y.get(),))` - In this query, you have only one placehoder '?',but trying to send two values so that is the issue the user is talking about. with one place holder you can pass only one value.

Comment: Also, let me know if this works and if that's what you are looking for

Comment: I know. I had also tried to write SET values=?, ?", but I received the same problem. Why?

Comment: you cannot directly use placeholders like that for multiple values in the `SET`clause of an `UPDATE`statement. you have to specify seperately - `"UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET column1=?, column2=? WHERE id=?", (value1, value2, id)`

Comment: Yes, your answer is what I was looking for, thanks. Now i vote for you and i accept the answer, don't worry :) But I'm trying to understand some things for a moment: what difference is there between using your first code (the one with two connect.executes) and between using this UPDATE Valori_Textbox SET column1=? , column2=? WHERE id=?”, (value1, value2, id)? (in my case, how should I write this sql?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255487/discussion-between-prudhviraj-and-horiatiki).

Comment: I would also like to ask you something about your update of the pythonica solution. you wrote that it works "if the ID's value keeps on increasing like 1,2,3". Does it also work if the first iD starts for example from 9 (and not from 1) and if the order has numerically non-consecutive IDs? For example: 9, 12, 13, 20, 22?